# Dafny - Violating Modifies when Calling in Loop

Tags: dynamic-arrays, dafny

The following is based off of [Secure Foundations's dafny implementation of a Dynamic Array](https://github.com/secure-foundations/everquic-dafny/blob/master/src/DynamicArray.dfy).

I'm trying to create a test method that when calling `push_back`, invokes `extend_buffer`.  This requires a prefix: calling `push_back` enough times to fill it up so the next time it's called, the buffer is extended.  With a default size of 16, the prefix would consist of calling `push_back` 15 times.  I find that if I make the call 15 times it verifies, but if I instead try to call in a for loop, I get the error `call may violate context's modifies clause`.

```
class Vector<T> {

    static const DEFAULT_SIZE := 16
    var buffer : array<T>
    var capacity : int
    var size : int

    predicate Valid()
    reads this, buffer
    {
        capacity >= DEFAULT_SIZE
        && capacity as int == buffer.Length
        && 0 <= size < capacity
    }

    method extend_buffer(value: T)
    requires Valid()
    ensures Valid()
    ensures fresh(buffer)
    ensures size as int < capacity as int - 1
    ensures forall i : int :: 0 <= i < old(size) ==> buffer[i] == old(buffer[i])
    ensures size == old(size)
    ensures capacity == old(capacity) as int * 2
    ensures buffer.Length == old(buffer.Length) * 2
    modifies this`capacity, this`buffer
    {
        var old_buffer := this.buffer;
        var old_size := this.capacity;


        capacity := old_size * 2;
        buffer := newArrayFill(capacity, value);

        var i:= 0;
        while i < old_size
        invariant Valid();
        invariant capacity > old_size;
        invariant i < capacity;
        invariant i < old_size;
        invariant fresh(buffer)
        invariant size < capacity - 1;
        invariant size == old(size)
        invariant capacity == old(capacity) * 2
        invariant forall k : int :: 0 <= k < i ==> buffer[k] == old_buffer[k] == old(buffer[k])
        {
            buffer[i] := old_buffer[i];

            if i == old_size - 1 {
                break;
            }
            i := i + 1;
        }
    }

    method push_back(value:T)
    requires Valid()
    ensures Valid();
    ensures old(size as int) < buffer.Length
    ensures buffer[old(size)] == value
    ensures size == old(size) + 1
    ensures if old(size) + 1 == old(capacity) then fresh(buffer) else buffer == old(buffer)
    ensures forall i : int :: 0 <= i < old(size) ==> buffer[i] == old(buffer[i])
    ensures forall i : int :: size <= i < old(buffer.Length) ==> buffer[i] == old(buffer[i])
    ensures if size == old(capacity) then fresh(buffer) else !fresh(buffer) && buffer == old(buffer)
    modifies this, this.buffer, this`size
    {
        if (size + 1 == capacity)
        {
            extend_buffer(value);
        }
        buffer[size] := value;
        size := size + 1;
    }

    method {:extern "Extern", "newArrayFill"} newArrayFill<T>(n: int, t: T) returns (ar: array<T>)
    ensures ar.Length == n as int
    ensures forall i | 0 <= i < n :: ar[i] == t
    ensures fresh(ar)

    constructor(default_val:T)
    ensures Valid()
    ensures fresh(buffer)
    ensures size == 0
    ensures capacity == DEFAULT_SIZE 
    ensures capacity as int == buffer.Length
    {
        size := 0;
        capacity := DEFAULT_SIZE;
        new;
        buffer := newArrayFill(DEFAULT_SIZE, default_val);
    }
}

method push_back_should_extend()
{
    var arr := new Vector(0);
    label L:
    var oracleValue := 7;

    for i : int := 0 to arr.capacity - 1
    invariant arr.Valid()
    {
        arr.push_back(oracleValue);
    }

}
```

I'm assuming the issue arises from push_back claiming it modifies `this`, which I feel is overstating what it actually modifies, but when I remove `this`, the error just moves to the call to `extend_buffer`.

Interestingly, adding in the following twostate:

```
twostate predicate sameBuffer(v: Vector)
reads v`buffer
{
    v.buffer == old(v.buffer)
}
```

and then adding `invariant sameBuffer@L(arr)` to `push_back_should_extend`'s for loop also doesn't verify, even though it's clear from `ensures if old(size) + 1 == old(capacity) then fresh(buffer) else !fresh(buffer) && buffer == old(buffer)` that the memory for buffer doesn't change throughout the prefix.

I feel this could be addressed by an inductive lemma, but while I understand the form of lemma's, I lack the ability to apply and derive them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
invariant fresh(arr.buffer)
```

to the for loop seems to fix it. Does that do what you want?

Comment: That did it, thank you.  Leave it to me try to overengineer a solution.